# A promQL query to calculate the difference between now and one day ago ( consider zero if no data)?

Tags: prometheus

My metric, which is of type ‘counter’, is named ‘http_counters’ and has two labels: ‘node’ and ‘status’.

I want to calculate the difference between the current counter value and the value from 1 day ago, categorized by ‘node’ and ‘status’.

Please note, if there is no data from 1 day ago, the value from 1 day ago is considered as zero. Also, the difference still retains the two labels ‘node’ and ‘status’

I think the statement is about:

```
http_counters{} - (http_counters{} offset 1d or on(????) vector(????))
```

How fill it? thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way here is not to apply or inside of the right operand, but to whole expression instead:

```
http_counters - http_counters offset 1d
 or http_counters
```

Here, you'll get difference for cases when metric was present an our ago, and if it was not, you'll get current value instead.

---

Please, be advised about possible issues near counter resets: you might get large negative values as a result of your query. Function `increase` accounts for counter resets automatically (but it has it's own problems, like unexpected extrapolated)